# React: How to prevent an integer value turning to NaN after form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm building a tax calculator using React. As the moment it's comprised of just two functions. handleInputChange is used to render the 'rate' and 'totalFees' values in the browser in real-time as they are being entered. handleSubmit makes the calculations once the user has inputted the value for 'rate'.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        rate: 0,
        totalFees: 0,
        incomeTax: 0,
        nationalInsurance: 0,
        combined: 0,
        insideAnnual: 0,
        insideMonthly: 0
    }
}

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)
    }, () => {
        this.setState({
            totalFees: parseInt(this.state.rate * 220, 10)
        })
    })
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const rate = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    const totalFees = parseInt(rate * 220, 10);
    let incomeTax = 0;
    let nationalInsurance = 0;

    if (totalFees <= 8632) {
        incomeTax = 0;
        nationalInsurance = 0;
    } else if (totalFees <= 12500) {
        incomeTax = 0;
        nationalInsurance = ((totalFees - 8632) * .12);
    } else if (totalFees <= 50000) {
        incomeTax = ((totalFees - 12500) * .2);
        nationalInsurance = ((totalFees - 8632) * .12);
    } else if (totalFees <= 150000) {
        incomeTax = (7500 + ((totalFees - 50000) * .4));
        nationalInsurance = (4964.16 + ((totalFees - 50000) * .02));
    } else {
        incomeTax = (47500 + ((this.state.totalFees - 150000) * .45));
        nationalInsurance = (4964.16 + ((this.state.totalFees - 50000) * .02));
    }

    const combined = incomeTax + nationalInsurance;
    const insideAnnual = parseInt(totalFees, 10) - parseInt(combined, 10);
    const insideMonthly = Math.round((insideAnnual / 12) * 100) / 100;

    this.setState({
        rate: rate,
        totalFees: totalFees,
        incomeTax: incomeTax,
        nationalInsurance: nationalInsurance,
        combined: combined,
        insideAnnual: insideAnnual,
        insideMonthly: insideMonthly
    });
}
```

My problem is that, once the form has been submitted, the values for 'totalFees' and 'rate' turn to NaN. Curiously, whereas the calculations for 'incomeTax', 'nationalInsurance' and 'combined' work (meaning they are based on the original input for 'rate' and the resulting 'totalFees' value), NaN is returned for my other variable values. Can somebody explain why the variables in question return NaN upon the form submit and what I can do to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: check if handleSubmit isn't called multiple times. Also do as much console.logs as possible, example for event.target.value in handleSubmit method.

Comment: 'totalFees' and 'rate' variables, who doesn't work, are only consts in your code. try also changing them to let, cause it can be reference issue.

Comment: I dont understand the part why are you performing `parseInt` on the `event.target.value` in `handleSubmit` where the `event.target` usually is the `form` itself if you had mapped the `handleSubmit` to `onSubmit`. So your `rate` would obviously go to `NaN` and since you are setting it into state, the inputs will also reflect the same value. But you already have `rate` and `totalfees` in state via `handleInputChagne`. Why do you need to recalculate them in `handleSubmit` and why not use the one in state already. Let me know if my understanding is different

Answer (score 1):

Dont use parseInt everywhere, when its already int u dont need to parse it:

try there changes:

```
handleInputChange = (event:any) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
                //changed here
                totalFees: this.state.rate * 220
            })
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (event:any) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const rate = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
        //changed here
        const totalFees = rate * 220
        let incomeTax = 0;
        let nationalInsurance = 0;

        if (totalFees <= 8632) {
            incomeTax = 0;
            nationalInsurance = 0;
        } else if (totalFees <= 12500) {
            incomeTax = 0;
            nationalInsurance = ((totalFees - 8632) * .12);
        } else if (totalFees <= 50000) {
            incomeTax = ((totalFees - 12500) * .2);
            nationalInsurance = ((totalFees - 8632) * .12);
        } else if (totalFees <= 150000) {
            incomeTax = (7500 + ((totalFees - 50000) * .4));
            nationalInsurance = (4964.16 + ((totalFees - 50000) * .02));
        } else {
            incomeTax = (47500 + ((this.state.totalFees - 150000) * .45));
            nationalInsurance = (4964.16 + ((this.state.totalFees - 50000) * .02));
        }

        const combined = incomeTax + nationalInsurance;
        //changed here
        const insideAnnual = totalFees - combined
        const insideMonthly = Math.round((insideAnnual / 12) * 100) / 100;

        this.setState({
            rate: rate,
            totalFees: totalFees,
            incomeTax: incomeTax,
            nationalInsurance: nationalInsurance,
            combined: combined,
            insideAnnual: insideAnnual,
            insideMonthly: insideMonthly
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I started adding an excessive amount of parseInt's when I was struggling to find a solution. Issue's resolved now, as a result of one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prop-types to control the data types of your variables.
For example: Filename: Persons.js

Step 1:

Import the library:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
```

Step 2:

```
class Person extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Person'>
            <p onClick={this.props.xyz}>I am {this.props.name} and I am {this.props.age} years old!</p>
            <p>{this.props.children}</p>
           <input type="text" onChange={this.props.xyzchanged} defaultValue={this.props.name}/>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

Person.propTypes = {
    xyz:PropTypes.func,
    name:PropTypes.string.isRequired, // name is required to be passed when called in Persons.js render method
    age:PropTypes.number,
    xyzchanged:PropTypes.func
}

export default Person;
```

using prop-types, if the variable doesn't have the data type you are expecting you will see a warning in the console. Also, I would suggest you use console.log too.